# string gets filled with garbage

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, printf, c-strings

i got a string and a scanf that reads from input until it finds a *, which is the character i picked for the end of the text. After the * all the remaining cells get filled with random characters.
I know that a string after the \0 character if not filled completly until the last cell will fill all the remaining empty ones with \0, why is this not the case and how can i make it so that after the last letter given in input all the remaining cells are the same value?

```
    char string1 [100];

    scanf("%[^*]s", string1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        printf("\n %d=%d",i,string1[i]);
}
```

if i try to input something like hello*, here's the output:

```
 0=104   
 1=101   
 2=108   
 3=108   
 4=111   
 5=0
 6=0
 7=0
 8=92
 9=0
 10=68
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an uninitialized array:

```
char string1 [100];
```

that has indeterminate values. You could initialize the array like

```
char string1 [100] = { 0 };
```

or

```
char string1 [100] = "";
```

In this call

```
scanf("%[^*]s", string1);
```

you need to remove the trailing character `s`, because `%[]` and `%s` are distinct format specifiers. There is no `%[]s` format specifier. It should look like this:

```
scanf("%[^*]", string1);
```

The array contains a string terminated by the zero character `'\0'`.

So to output the string you should write for example

```
for ( int i = 0; string1[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    printf( "%c", string1[i] ); // or putchar( string1[i] );
putchar( '\n' );
```

or like

```
for ( int i = 0; string1[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    printf("\n %d=%c",i,string1[i]);
putchar( '\n' );
```

or just

```
puts( string1 );
```

As for your statement

```
printf("\n %d=%d",i,string1[i]);
```

then it outputs each character (including non-initialized characters) as integers due to using the conversion specifier `d` instead of `c`. That is the function outputs internal ASCII representations of characters.

Comment: but why does the string keep having values different from \0 even if it's supposed to be terminated? if I do a for cycle with 100 iterations and my string gets terminated with a \0 at i=5 I'd expect that from that point onwards all the remaining uninitialised cells will also be \0

Comment: @Gioloh As I wrote in the answer the array was not initialized and has indeterminate values. You should declare the array like for example char string1[100] = { 0 };

Comment: that fixed it! Didn't know that declaring an array without initializing it would bring to that behaviour ty so much for clarifying

Comment: @Gioloh If the array would be declared in the file scope then it would be implicitly zero initialized as an array having static storage duration. Variables declared in block scopes that have automatic storage duration are not initialized implicitly. You need to initialize them explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that a string after the \0 character if not filled completly
> until the last cell will fill all the remaining empty ones with \0

No, that's not true.
It couldn't be true: there is no length to a string. No where neither the compiler nor any function can even know what is the size of the string. Only you do. So, no, string don't autofill with '\0'

Keep in minds that there aren't any string types in C. Just pointer to chars (sometimes those pointers are constant pointers to an array, but still, they are just pointers. We know where they start, but there is no way (other than deciding it and being consistent while coding) to know where they stop.

Sure, most of the time, there is an obvious answer, that make obvious for any reader of the code what is the size of the allocated memory.

For example, when you code

```c
char string1[20];
sprintf(string1, "hello");
```

it is quite obvious for a reader of that code that the allocated memory is 20 bytes. So you may think that the compiler should know, when sprinting in it of sscaning to it, that it should fill the unused part of the 20 bytes with 0. But, first of all, the compiler is not there anymore when you will sscanf or sprintf. That occurs at runtime, and compiler is at compilation time. At run time, there is not trace of that `20`.

Plus, it can be more complicated than that

```c
void fillString(char *p){
    sprintf(p, "hello");
}

int main(){
    char string1[20];
    string1[0]='O';
    string1[1]='t';
    fillString(&(string1[2]));
}
```

How in this case does `sprintf` is supposed to know that it must fill 18 bytes with the string then '\0'?

And that is for normal usage. I haven't started yet with convoluted but legal usages. Such as using `char buffer[1000];` as an array of 50 length-20 strings (`buffer`, `buffer+20`, `buffer+40`, ...) or things like

```c
union {
    char str[40];
    struct {
        char substr1[20];
        char substr2[20];
    } s;
}
```

So, no, strings are not filled up with '\0'. That is not the case. It is not the habit in C to have implicit thing happening under the hood. And that could not be the case, even if we wanted to.

Your "star-terminated string" behaves exactly as a "null-terminated string" does. Sometimes the rest of the allocated memory is full of 0, sometimes it is not. The `scanf` won't touch anything else that what is strictly needed. The rest of the allocated memory remains untouched. If that memory happened to be full of '\0' before the call to `scanf`, then it remains so. Otherwise not. Which leads me to my last remark: you seem to believe that it is `scanf` that fills the memory with non-null chars. It is not. Those chars were already there before. If you had the feeling that some other methods fill the rest of memory with '\0', that was just an impression (a natural one, since most of the time, newly allocated memory are 0. Not because a rule says so. But because that is the most frequent byte to be found in random area of memory. That is why uninitialized variables bugs are so painful: they occur only from times to times, because very often uninitialized variables are 0, just by chance, but still they are)

Comment: In your answer, you wrote: `So, no, strings are not filled up with '\0'.` -- This statement is mostly correct. However, one exception is [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy). I am not recommending that you change your answer to fix this statement, because it is mostly correct and changing it would probably make your answer unnecessarily complicated and distract from the point that you are making. However, I thought that this would still be worth mentioning in a comment.

Comment: Indeed. But even then, `strncpy`, strictly speaking, does not fill the "string" (I the meaning the OP is intending, that is "the memory that was allocated for the string) with '\0'. It fills the rest of the `n` bytes with `\0`. You still need to tell `strncpy` what is `n`. And you can `char str[20]; strncpy(str, "hello", 10);`, or even `char str[20]; strncpy(str, "hello", 40);` (which is a very bad idea, even in the case of my `union` example, but still, you can: `strncpy` doesn't care)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, but you're right. That may even be the reason why the OP thinks `strings are filled with 0`. Except that in their usage, they have no such code filling anything (even dangerously so: their usage of `scanf("%[^*]", string1)` is insecure: nothing here will, fill the "rest of string1" with '\0', but, more seriously, nothing with ensure that what ever is written fits in `string1` (if user inputs more than 99 chars, that is, in the best case, a segmentation fault, in the worse, a seemingly harmless overwriting over God knows what)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Regarding `scanf("%[^*]s", string1)`, I believe the most serious issue is that if the user simply enters `*`, then the `%[^*]` format specifier will not match anything (because it must match at least one character for the match to be successful), which means that `string1` is not guaranteed to contain a null terminating character (unless it was initialized).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create a zeroed array is to use calloc.
Try replacing
char string1 [100];
with
char *string1=calloc(1,100);

Comment: I disagree that `calloc` is "the easiest" way, because this would also require to call `free`. I see no reason to use dynamic memory allocation here, especially since dynamic memory allocation is generally bad for performance. The easiest way is to simply initialize the array, as shown in the other answer.

Comment: Okay, I get your point. I didn't know you can broadcast zeroes by just putting one in between the brackets.

Comment: In C, an object is either fully initialized or not initialized at all. Therefore, initializing one element of the array is sufficient to initialize the entire array. The rest of the array will be initialized to zero, irrespestive of the value of the first element. For example, `char string1[100] = {1};` will initialize the first element to `1`, but all remaining elements to `0`. Note that this only applies to actual initialization, so when declaring a variable. It does not apply to normal assignment outside a declaration, for example when writing `string1[5] = 'p';`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't know that. At least with calloc, you know it's all going to be zero. It's a method I trust as it can't be misinterpreted. Can you point me to documentation which describes the behaviour you've just described? Thanks.

Comment: I recommend [this documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization). It is not intended as a tutorial, but rather as a reference.

Comment: Thanks. That resource is for c++. I don't know where your way might fail, but I think I'll continue to use calloc as I suspect the broadcasting way may be dependent on compiler or c/c++ versions. Where a static array is needed, it can be allocated statically and zeroed dynamically. Thanks for providing the link though.

Comment: That page I linked to is for C, not C++. The site itself hosts references for both C and C++, but strictly distinguishes between both languages. The page I linked to contains a link to the corresponding C++ documentation, but the page itself is strictly C, not C++.

Comment: All compilers that comply with the ISO C standard are required to support initialization such as `char string1[100] = {0};`. No compiler-specific extensions are being used for this. Some C compilers also support `char string1[100] = {};`, which is the C++ way of writing it. Only the latter is a compiler-specific extension.